# Find Distinct Dates from Varchar Datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I have a column in database that is of type varchar and stores datetime values as under:

```
15-05-2017 16:36:49
14-05-2017 19:27:41
```

and so on

The format is `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

From MSSQL query, I want to fetch all the unique dates from this column. I have tried using DATE_FORMAT as suggested on one of the artiles in stackoverflow itself but it didnot work.

```
bs.com.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(dat, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dat) FROM table";
```

I expect outputs to be a list of unique dates fetched from the above mentioned column (without time).

I am using: MSSQL 2008 Express Edition and Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition.

Please note that I am using Inline Queries, not stored procedure.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function (on a column). It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. To make things clearer, remove those redundant parentheses! I.e.`SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(...`

Comment: Don't store date/time values in varchar columns! Use proper data types!

Comment: @jarlh The application already works on this column with varchar as datatype, so we cannot make changes now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast to `date`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(date as DATE)
FROM table;
```

The cast removes the time component before the count.  There is no need to convert the value to a string.

EDIT:

Do not store date/time values as string!  Use the correct data type.  But, because you are, you can just do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(date, 10)
FROM table;
```

Comment: @ITSagar . . . You should not be storing date/time values as strings.  Use the correct types!

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte([Datetime])
As
(
SELECT '15-05-2017 16:36:49'Union all --Sample date
SELECT '14-05-2017 19:27:41'Union all
SELECT '15-05-2017 16:36:49'Union all
SELECT '12-05-2017 19:27:41'Union all
SELECT '15-05-2017 16:36:49'Union all
SELECT '16-05-2017 19:27:41'Union all
SELECT '15-05-2017 16:36:49'Union all
SELECT '19-05-2017 19:27:41'Union all
SELECT '15-05-2017 16:36:49'Union all
SELECT '14-05-2017 19:27:41'
)
Select ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by (Select 1)) As Seq, [Datetime] From
(
select [Datetime],ROW_NUMBER()Over(Partition by [Datetime] order by [Datetime]) seq from cte
)dt
where dt.seq=1
```

OutPut of Distinct datecolumn

```
Seq Datetime
-----------------------
1   12-05-2017 19:27:41
2   14-05-2017 19:27:41
3   15-05-2017 16:36:49
4   16-05-2017 19:27:41
5   19-05-2017 19:27:41
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is same as Gordon but i have added dateformat in case your server have different dateformat style.

```
Declare @a table (date1 varchar(100))

Insert @a
select '15-04-2017 16:36:49'
union
select '14-04-2017 19:27:41'
union
select '15-05-2017 19:20:41'

set dateformat dmy;
select distinct convert(date,date1,105) from @a
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(CAST(dat,dat1,105)) FROM table gives: Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.